# Is it possible to use form helpers with a collection of ActiveModels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm wrapping all of our api calls inside ActiveModels.

I don't really have a good way to maintain relationships using ActiveModel so inside each model I'm using arrays to hold child ActiveModel objects.

I'd like to be able to use form helpers in my views.

If I have an Application that has n questions I had hoped to be able to do something like:

```
<%= form_for @application, :url => { :action => "application_submit" } do |a| %>
  <%= fields_for @application.questions do |q| %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work because questions is an array of AvtiveModel objects

Is it going to be possible for me to use form helpers for ActiveModels with no relationships?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation for [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) has the answer under One-to-many

You need to define (association_name)_attributes

```
def questions_attributes=(attributes)
  # Process the attributes hash
end
```